# Mapping software for creating paths on android

Tags: mapping, android-app, gps-tracking, kml

We live on a farm which is quite large and mountainous and we would like to be able to map all the routes as we drive using the gps on an Android cellphone.

Do you have any suggestions on which software to use? Preferably the software should be freeware and able to export to .kml or a similar format.

Answer (score 1):

I've regularly used [GPS Logger](https://github.com/BasicAirData/GPSLogger) for that tasks.

Some facts:

- The app is 100% free and open source.
- Share trips in KML, GPX, and TXT format in many ways.
- The application is freely downloadable from [Google Play(tm)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.basicairdata.graziano.gpslogger)

I thought I have downloaded it from F-Droid but couldn't find it there anymore.